# Prove that if $m,n,l \in \Bbb N$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(m+l,m)=\operatorname{lcm}(n+l,n)$, then $m=n$ is the only satisfactory solution.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I've already solved this question but I have done so by equating the lower bounds of the lcm function.

WLOG x>=y then x<=lcm(x,y)<=xy

m+l <= [m+l,m] <= m^2+ml and n+l <= [n+l,n] <= n^2+nl , since neither can be lower than the other (easily proved by contradiction) m=l

I wanted to know if this is actually allowed or if there is a counterexample to this method (since it seems so much more easier than forming equations).

Thanks

Comment: It isn’t clear from your description exactly what you did; please explain more clearly.

Comment: WLOG x>=y then x<=lcm(x,y)<=xy

Comment: And exactly how did you use that inequality? What, precisely, is your argument?

Comment: m+l <= [m+l,m] <= m^2+ml and n+l <= [n+l,n] <= n^2+nl , since neither can be lower than the other (easily proved by contradiction) m=l

Comment: I repeat: what, precisely, is your argument? What chain of reasoning leads from those inequalities to the conclusion that $m=n$? We can’t evaluate the legitimacy of the argument until we know what the argument is.

Comment: Is this valid ?

Comment: You haven’t told us what your argument **is**, so we can’t possibly tell you whether it’s valid. If there’s no more to it than what you’ve already written, then it isn’t even an argument, and you’ve not yet reached a point at which validity comes into question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107704/discussion-between-n-n-and-brian-m-scott).

Comment: "since neither can be lower than the other"  Are you saying $m+l < n+l$ is not possible and that $m^2 + l < n^2 + l$ is not possible?  Why the bleepity bleep not?  "since neither can be lower than the other" Since neither of *what* can be lower than the other *what*?  If it can be easily proven by contradiction please do so!  (But first it'd be nice if you actually *explained* what you are saying.  Neither *what* can be lower than the other *what*.  And why not?)

Comment: Okay, you seem to have $m < lcm(m,m+l)=lcm(n,n+1) < m^2 +ml$ and $n < lcm(m,m+l)=lcm(n,n+1) < m^2 + ml$. and somehow claim  this means $m = n$????? Why.   Consider $27 < 51 < 92$ and $35 < 51 < 104$.  Does that mean $27 = 35$??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$m$ is *one* lower bound of $lcm(m+l,m) = lcm(n+l,m)$ but we don't know that it is the *greatest* lower bound.

$n$ is *another* lower bound of $lcm(m+l, m) = lcm(n+l, m)$ but we don't know that it is the *greatest* lower bound. And we don't know that it is the *same* lower bound.

We can *not* use that $m\le lcm(m+l,m)=lcm(n+l,m)$ and $n\le lcm(m+l,m)=lcm(n+1,m)$ to conclude $m= n$.

After all.  If $lcm(m+l,m)=lcm(n+1,m) = K$ then $1,2,3,4,..........., K-2, K-1, K \le lcm(m+l,m)=lcm(n+1,m)$ and $m,n \in \{1,2,3,4,.....,K\}$ as are many other numbers.  That's no reason to assume that all the numbers are equal to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument does not make sense.  You have two bounds on the $\operatorname{lcm}$, but then assert $m=l$(which should be $m=n$).  If $m=12,n=13,l=5$, for example, the bounds on the common $\operatorname{lcm}$ are $17 \le \operatorname{lcm} \le 204$ and $18 \le \operatorname{lcm} \le 221$.  There is a lot of overlap.  Nothing you have said prevents the $\operatorname{lcm}$ from being something like $100$ or $150$.  There can't be a counterexample because the underlying claim is true, but the proposed proof is inadequate.